# each & for loop mixed up my array order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created an associative array for index spaces inside a sentence for example:

sentence: hello            how are you? (spaces between the word 'hello' to 'how')

so my array looks like this:

```
indexed_words[0] = hello 
indexed_words[0_1] = space
indexed_words[0_2] = space
indexed_words[0_3] = space
indexed_words[0_4] = space
indexed_words[0_5] = space
indexed_words[0_6] = space
indexed_words[0_7] = space
indexed_words[1] = how
indexed_words[2] = are
indexed_words[3] = you?
```

but when I use 'for' loop its show me (using alert) the indexes 0,1,2,3 first and after them the sub-indexes, its mixed up my array order, any idea?

here my code:

```
function words_indexer(user_content)
{

        var words_array = user_content.split(" ");

        var indexed_words = {}; 

        var word_counter = 0

        var last_word_counter = 0

        $.each(user_content, function(word_key,word_value){


            if(word_value === ''){

                var indexed_key = last_word_counter + '_' + word_key;

                indexed_words[indexed_key] = word_value;


            }else{              

                var indexed_key = word_counter;

                indexed_words[indexed_key] = word_value;

                last_word_counter = word_counter;

                word_counter++;             
            }

        }); 


        for (var key in indexed_words) {
            alert(key + ' ' + indexed_words[key]);
        }       
}
```

Comment: please add what you like to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

If your array index needs an extra level of structure then it may be better to just create a nested array instead:

```
indexed_words[0] = hello 
indexed_words[0][1] = space
indexed_words[0][2] = space
indexed_words[0][3] = space
indexed_words[0][4] = space
indexed_words[0][5] = space
indexed_words[0][6] = space
indexed_words[0][7] = space
indexed_words[1] = how
indexed_words[2] = are
indexed_words[3] = you?
```

I believe adding an underscore to your array key may actually cause Javascript to consider it as being a string which would bump your numeric keys up above it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use non-numeric indexes for arrays in javascript (a_b is not considered numeric). For this you probably should use an object. And then loop through it like this:

```
for(var word_key in indexed_words) {
   if(!indexed_words.hasOwnProperty(word_key)) continue;
   var word_value = indexed_words[word_key];
   // Your code
}
```